# How can I run a playbook for each user on the machine

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

On our Linux workstations we have an AD user setup, so that when a user access a machine it will generate a /home/{username} folder, with all of the items defined in our skel. So each machine in our pool have different and multiple user folders.

I need to modify some files that are located in each of these user folders. How can I make ansible loop through each folder in the /home/* folder, so that the playbook is being applied to all of the users?

It should be noted that the playbook is being run as root, so I don't need to run the playbook itself as the user.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what error is it producing?

Comment: I can't find any entry in the documentation about this. Looking at the documentation https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html I have to provide the data for the loops and can't seem to find a way to pick up the data (like the list of folders in a folder)

Comment: So, `- {shell: /bin/ls -1d /home/*, register: list_homes}` didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, this is the wrong way to approach this - hopefully your company has a record of who *should* have access to each system, and a provision to get those accounts setup automatically on each system.  Given that, this is a good example of "we need to fix this today while we get the better solution setup."

The example that @mdaniel provided should work.  You can implement this in a playbook like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
  - name: "Get home directories"
    shell: /bin/ls -d /home/*
    register: home_dirs

  - name: "Touch files"
    debug:
      msg: "Working on {{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ home_dirs.stdout_lines }}"
```

Of course replace the "debug:" module with your tasks to automate.